How to get pivot with no specific pattern
I am looking for a way to handle following pivot situation.
Example data:



name




A


Alan


B


Bacon


Bob


Boyd


C


Carl


Chris


Colden


D


Diana



Now I want to get this output:



column1
column2




A
Alan


B
Bacon, Bob, Boyd


C
Carl, Chris, Colden


D
Diana



I tried:
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) AS column1,
       STRING_AGG(name, ', ' ORDER BY name) AS column2
FROM info
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)
ORDER BY column1;

but I got:



column1
column2




A
A, Alan


B
B, Bacon, Bob, Boyd


C
C, Carl, Chris, Colden


D
D, Diana



I don't know how to remove 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' in column2, is there any way?(BTW, I use PieCloudDB database, if you haven’t heard of it, you can use PostgreSQL to demo instead. Thank You!)

WHERE len(name) > 1?

Is there are reason you have the letters as rows in your table? If you simply drop those rows your existing query will achieve the desired result. If you really need to record the first letter of each record the you should put it in a second column on each row

solution will be suggested based on the the answer of why you need single letter in your table

Well, the data was crawled using Python, and I retained the 26 capital letters. At that time, I wanted to implement a feature that, during traversal, first identifies the initial letter and then retrieves the desired name.

In that case you have the option of implementing some logic in your data crawler to prevent the letter records being inserted into the data then using your original query. Otherwise you could use one of the given answers that would filter your letters from your results. I would suggest the first option

If column 2 don't have value, do you want to show record? if you don't want, you can try my way:
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) AS column1,
    STRING_AGG(name, ', ' ORDER BY name) AS column2
FROM 
    info
WHERE 
    LENGTH(name) > 1  -- Exclude single-letter rows (like 'A', 'B', etc.)
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)
ORDER BY 
    column1;



Sorry, my reputation is not high enough for me to add a comment, I think you can simply use 'case when' to filter the 'A','B'...
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) AS column1, 
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN LENGTH(name) > 1 THEN name END, ', ' ORDER BY name) AS column2
FROM info
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)
ORDER BY column1;

